# sprintf and concatenating string (c++)

Tags: c++

Are there specific instances in which this will cause problems for me? Because I have a bug that I'm pretty sure is because of this

```
#define customStringDataType extern string

char buffer[2024];
customStringDataType DATA;

sprintf(buffer, "Some cool information");
DATA = DATA + buffer;
```

EDIT: I'm sorry, I meant to say besides that. I know about the buffer overflow. Because I can set a large char buffer much longer than the info in it, and I'm still having the issue

Comment: Everytime that "some cool information" uses more bytes than the size of buffer. Use snprintf to avoid that.

Comment: Please post in the question what you were trying to do, smells like X-Y question.

Comment: Start by properly tagging the question. [tag:c] is not [tag:c++], and [tag:c++] is not [tag:c].

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++.

Comment: Why are you not doing `DATA = DATA + bufffer + "Some cool information";`?

Comment: @IInspectable: OP explicitly asks for C++, so the C tag is wrong. (Allthough I agree he should make up his mnd and ask fo C instead. Until then ..)

Comment: I tagged it because using string is c++ while using the buffer is C. I disagree with you guys.

Comment: Please post code that demonstrates the bug, not just the part you suspect. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `string` is not C++. `std::string` is.

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: @user121615: If it does not compile with a C compiler,it is not C - point.

Comment: `strcpy(buffer, "Some cool information");` or `sprintf(buffer, "%s", "Some cool information");`. Buffer overflow concerns aside, but  `sprintf(buffer, "Some cool information");` will fail badly if the string contains an `%s` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there specific instances in which this will cause problems for me?

It will be a problem if the length of the string being copied to `buffer` is equal to or greater than `1024`.

You can use `snprintf` to prevent buffer overflow.

```
sprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "Some cool information");
```

It's not clear why you are using `sprintf` in the first place. If `"Some cool information"` is supposed to contain formatting directives and there are more arguments in the call to `sprintf`, what you are trying makes some sense. If there are no other arguments to `sprintf`, you can simply use:

```
DATA += "Some cool information";
```

You can avoid the buffer size limitation problems by using `std::ostringstream`.

```
std::ostringstream ostr;
ostr << "Some cool information" << and other arguments as needed;
DATA += ostr.str();
```